# Block display depending on the result of the script

Tags: javascript, css

There is a script that loads a block from a specific page (it is installed on another).Everything works well, the output is an integer. Here's the question itself - how can I implement it so that the div is displayed depending on the result of the script? That is, if the result of work is more than 5, then hide the div; if not, do nothing.

the page (address) on which the script is installed - /board/ ;///
the page (address) from where the number is loaded - /$USER_ID ;///
$USER_ID - the ID of the user who is viewing the site (implemented in php) ;///
$board-ents - the number of user ads on his page (integer) (implemented in php);

script:

```
document.write('<span class="h19"></span>');
$.get("/$USER_ID",
  function(data) {
    var ifnohist = $(".board-ents:first", data).html();
    $(".board-ents:lt(1)", data).each(function() {
      var histr = $(this).html();
      $('.h19').before(histr);
    });
  });
```

block on another page:

```
<b class="board-ents">$board-ents</b>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain what "if the result of work is more than 5" means?

Comment: the script loads the number, an integer prime number. and now, if the number is greater than 5, then we need to apply display: none to the required element

Comment: `$('.required-element').toggle(response > 5)`?

Comment: This will not work, the script has no results actually .. you can try it on any site